# Look into ceph resiliance on openstack autopilot

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot, ceph

I now have a 7 node openstack cluster created via landscape/autopilot. I chose ceph for everything.

After getting into juju / looking into ceph.

```
juju ssh ceph/0  
root@topdesk:~# rados df
pool name       category                 KB      objects       clones     degraded      unfound           rd        rd KB           wr        wr KB
.rgw            -                          2            6            0            0           0           20           14           23            6
.rgw.buckets    -                          2            4            0            0           0          108           90           24            5
.rgw.buckets.index -                          0            3            0            0           0           25           22           19            0
.rgw.control    -                          0            8            0            0           0            0            0            0            0
.rgw.gc         -                          0           32            0            0           0          828          828          576            0
.rgw.root       -                          1            3            0            0           0           24           16            3            3
.users.uid      -                          1            5            0            0           0           17           13           18            3
cinder          -                    4588521         1905            0            0           0         2120         6610         6679      3500193
data            -                          0            0            0            0           0            0            0            0            0
glance          -                   12636624         1557            0            0           0         1122      2737602         3140     12636631
metadata        -                          0            0            0            0           0            0            0            0            0
rbd             -                          0            0            0            0           0            0            0            0            0
  total used        52120568         3523
  total avail    11725934688
  total space    11778055256
root@topdesk:~# ceph osd lspools
0 data,1 metadata,2 rbd,3 .rgw.root,4 .rgw.control,5 .rgw,6 .rgw.gc,7 .users.uid,8 cinder,9 glance,10 .rgw.buckets.index,11 .rgw.buckets,
```

1. How do I see how much "resiliance" I have, as in how many times is the data replicated?
2. Are the instances also stored on ceph so that I can do live migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the resilience of your data, try

```
sudo ceph osd dump | less
```

In the beginning of the output, it will show you the pools and the replicated size or the erasure coding count depending upon your setup.

Instance live migration depends upon the type of volume storage used. If its a volume backed storage, then you can use live migration. (And yes, those volumes also reside on Ceph).

Comment: Thanks, I can see the replicated size of 3 on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Ceph resiliency in Autopilot is 3 replicas. No erasure coding is used, as it is not presently recommended for block.